# Why do '*' vs list comprehension when making list of lists work differently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

My purpose was to make 2D list by `*`

```py
list2 = [[False]*2]*3 #[[False,False],[False,False],[False,False]]
list3 = [[False]*2 for _ in range(3)] #same as list2
list2[0][0] = True # [[True, False], [True, False], [True, False]]
list3[0][0] = True # [[True, False], [False, False], [False, False]]
```

`list3` works well but `list2` doesn't. **`list2` is affected by 'x' of list2[z][x].**

What happened?

Comment: list2 is working as shallow copy & list3 is working as deep copy

Comment: yes, i think you're right. thanks! and the referenced question also was perfect

Answer (score 0):

`*` operator concats the list and makes same replica or reference of the list so change made at one place will get replicated at all places whereas `for _ range(3)` will evaluate one by one hence making just one change at position `list[0][0]`